# Coq: Derive argument from context

Tags: coq, boilerplate

```
  (* I have a section with many variables and definitions. *)
  Section SectionWithDefs.

    Context {A B C: Type}.

    Variable arg1: A -> B.
    Variable arg2: B -> C.

    (* Functions that uses these variables. *)
    Definition f a := arg2 (arg1 a).  
      ...

  End SectionWithDefs.

  (* Now I want to use some of these functions. *)
  Section AnotherSection.

    Context {A B C: Type}.

    (* Here are the arguments. *)
    Variable arg1: A -> B.
    Variable arg2: B -> C.

    Variable a: A.

    Section CallFunctionWithArgiments.

      (* We can directly pass the arguments to the function...*)
      Eval compute in (f arg1 arg2 a).

    End CallFunctionWithArgiments.

    Section LetBlock.

      (* ... or we can create a sequence of let expression. *)
      Let f := f arg1 arg2.
        ...

      Eval compute in (f a).

    End LetBlock.

  End AnotherSection.
```

It is really hard to use the first approach since it is very difficult to maintain such code. Writing becomes really painful when there are more than five different functions with 4-5 arguments each.

The second case is more convenient. But I still have a lot of extra lines with "let" declarations:

```
   Let f1 := ... 
   Let f2 := ...
      ...
   Let fn := ...
```

Is there any way to avoid this extra boilerplate? Ideally, I want Coq to just "guess" correct arguments using types or even names of terms in a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the context (i.e., the list of `arg1`, `arg2`, etc.) is simple enough, you could use type classes to not have to pass arguments around.

```
  (* I have a section with many variables and definitions. *)
  Section SectionWithDefs.

    Context {A B C: Type}.

    Class Arg1 : Type := arg1 : A -> B.
    Context `{IArg1 : Arg1}.

    Class Arg2 : Type := arg2 : B -> C.
    Context `{IArg2 : Arg2}.

    (* Functions that uses these variables. *)
    Definition f a := arg2 (arg1 a).  

    (* ... *)

  End SectionWithDefs.

  (* Now I want to use some of these functions. *)
  Section AnotherSection.

    Context {A B C: Type}.

    (* Here are the arguments. *)
    Context `{MyIArg1 : Arg1 A B}.
    Context `{MyIArg2 : Arg2 B C}.

    Variable a: A.

    Section CallFunctionWithInstances.

      (* The implicit type class arguments [IArg1] and [IArg2] are
         resolved using instances in scope...*)
      Compute (f a).

    End CallFunctionWithInstances.

  End AnotherSection.
```

Comment: How come you annotated the return type in `Compute (f a : C)`? Seems like it should work without it.

Comment: No particular reason, it does work without :) I'll edit it out.